# Zip an archive without including parent directory

Tags: command-line, compression, zip

I want to zip many folders in a directory tree like so

```
V-
 something.txt
 folder
 folder
 g.jpg
 h.jar
```

When I try to zip it, it ends creating a zip archive with the v folder instead of the contents of it (the sub directories and files)

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you are trying to archive the files & folders in a particular folder but without including the root folder.

Example:

```
/test/test.txt
/test/test2.txt
```

where test.txt and test2.txt would be stored in the zip, but not /test/

You could cd into the /test/ directory then run something like,

```
zip -r filename.zip ./*
```

Which would create an archive in the same folder named filename.zip.
Or if running it from outside the folder you could run,

```
zip -r test.zip test/*
```

The /* is the part that includes only the contents of the folder, instead of the entire folder.

Edit: OP wanted multiple zips, solution ended up being a bit of a hack, I am curious as to whether there is a better way of doing this.

```
for d in */ ; do base=$(basename "$d") ; cd $base ; zip -r $base * ; mv "${base}.zip" .. ; cd .. ; done;
```

Comment: yes but i have a lot of file which i do the same thing on so it would tedious do it like that so is there like a bash script or something that would automate the same process on the directory that has all the folders

Comment: Oh, something like this then? (this would create archives of each folder within the current folder)

`for d in */ ; do base=$(basename "$d") ; zip -r "${base}.zip" "$d" ; done;`

Comment: Ok I ran the script and it created a the parent directory in the archive i want only the contents of the folder to be in the archive

Comment: my mistake, missed a bit of it. added a -j parameter which i just looked up, apparently skips the part you don't want. try this: `for d in */ ; do base=$(basename "$d") ; zip -rj "${base}.zip" "$d" ; done;`

Comment: Ok so i think the -j deflates all the folders in the archive so i have subfolders in the folder i want to archive to it deflates them also an them put them in the root of the archive

Comment: This is a bit of a hack and i feel like there should be a better way to do it... but i think this might do the trick. `for d in */ ; do base=$(basename "$d") ; cd $base ; zip -r $base * ; mv "${base}.zip" .. ; cd .. ; done;`

Comment: Thanks Dude The Hack Worked Now I can Continue With My Work

Comment: zip -r test.zip test/* from the outside adds test as directory into the zip file

Comment: as @smihael stated, `zip -r test.zip test/*` does not work. is there any correct way to achieve this from outside the directory?

Comment: For those who want to also archive dot files, `zip -r filename.zip ./*` will not work, please use `zip -r filename.zip .` instead.

Comment: This answer is wrong, unfortunately. Includes the parent directory, at least for Info-ZIP on mac os.

Comment: Doesn't work. @smihael pointed the issue out correctly.

Answer (score 73):

Hope this helps.

```
(cd directory && zip -r ../out.zip .)
```

It keeps the main shell in the same directory and only changing the directory of the sub-shell which dies after the command.

Comment: I wanted to add this as a comment to [@Alfred UC](https://askubuntu.com/users/484653/alfred-uc)'s answer but I don't have enough reputation for that.

Comment: If it actually solves the problem, then it may be a solution.

Comment: This is better as an answer. Does this work in both bash and sh?

Comment: @ArlenBeiler yes it does. You will need to make sure your installation has `zip` though.

Comment: hands down the most elegant one.

Comment: Also, other solutions such as using wildcard character * become problematic when dealing with very large number of files in the folder (throws "argument list too long" error). This solution doesn't present that problem

Answer (score 64):

Use the `-j` or `--junk-paths` option in your zip command.

From the [zip man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip):

> ```
> -j
>
> --junk-paths
>
> Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store directory 
> names. By default, zip will store the full path (relative to the current 
> directory).
> ```

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer.

Comment: What about nested paths/folders though?

Comment: This will omit all folders in the archive, and if you have duplicate file names in different folders, this will blow up. This has its place, but only if you don't care about folders and just want files. Not what the OP was asking for, but still good knowledge

Comment: ubuntu 20 bash : zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot repeat names in zip file)

Comment: Following up on @GuyPaddock's question, how do you junk the parent folder path but not the nested folders, is `cd path && zip...` the only way?

Answer (score 31):

How about this command?

```
$ cd somedir ; zip -r ../zipped.zip . * ; cd ..
```

Comment: While this is a correct answer, the introduction doesn't sound like you're convinced yourself. It would also help to explain a little bit, what the command does.

Comment: This was my solution too, but I dislike it because it involves `cd`. Was hoping there was a way to specify the stored path more precisely.

Comment: Only thing what worked for me,

Answer (score 6):

```bsh
cd `dirname path/to/archive` && zip -rq $OLDPWD/arhive.zip . && cd -
```

This works not only with flatten tree (like `-j`) and you can specify any dir (not only children)

Answer (score 4):

```
(cd MyDirectory && zip -r - .) >MyArchive.zip
```

This lets you specify the resulting filename relative to the current directory, rather than relative to the target directory.

As a bonus, this overwrites the archive instead of adding new files to it, which was desired in my case.

Instead of `.` you can specify files/directories relative to the target directory that you want to include.

Unlike `-j` it preserves paths relative to the target directory, rather than flattening all files into a single directory.

Comment: what does the extra - do?

Comment: @JosephAstrahan I believe it prints the result to stdout.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers did not satisfy me, because they either included the whole directory structure in the zip, or included an ugly `../../../../file.zip` path in the `zip` command.

The approach below uses a common piece of boilerplate code to get the current directory (the directory in which this script is located) as an absolute path.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)
(cd "path/to/some/deep/directory/" && zip -r "${dir}/file.zip" ./*)
```